# if statement in SQL computed Column Specification

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to built in if statement in computed column
What I'm trying to accomplish should look like this but this is more pseudo code:
SalePrice-Cost-(if(isConsigned=1 Then Payout else 0))

How do I this and can I use if statement inside computed column or it should be something else?

Comment: Use a `case` expression.

Comment: Ok How do I use case expression in this case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This:

```
SalePrice-Cost-(iif(isConsigned=1, Payout, 0))
```

Or

```
SalePrice-Cost-(CASE isConsigned WHEN 1 THEN Payout ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Or, to complete the set: `SalePrice - Cost - ( CASE WHEN isConsigned = 1 THEN Payout ELSE 0 END )`.

Comment: Does the computed column value update, if the input value comes from another table and updates its value? And does it update in case of a date which may pass?  Or does it only compute during add or update of the record?